# ng-repeat repeating item on splice instead of showing last item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I have the following `ng-repeat` that work fine.

```
<div ng-repeat="data in workflow.flow | orderBy:'+step_number'" ng-init="$stepIndex = workflow.flow.indexOf(data)">
    {{ workflow.flow[$stepIndex].step_number }}
</div>
```

### $scope.workflow.flow

```
[
  {
    "id":"1334f68db820f664",
    "step_number":1,
    "tasks":[ { "id":"1334f68e3f20f665" } ]
  },
  {
    "id":"134967a5ba205f5b",
    "step_number":2,
    "tasks":[ { "id":"134972c5b420e027" } ]
  },
  {
    "id":"1334f68e7d209ae6",
    "step_number":3,
    "tasks":[ { "id":"1334f68ef6209ae7" } ]
  }
]
```

This is how it displays in my html:

```
1 
2
3
```

---

I have the below function that adds a step into the middle of an array:

```
$scope.insertStep = function() {

    var insertStepIndex = 1, 
        task_data = {"id": null, "step_number": (insertStepIndex+2), "tasks": []};

    //go through each item in the array
    $.each($scope.workflow.flow, function(index, step){
        //if the step number is greater then the place you want to insert it into, increase the step numbers
        if(step.step_number > $scope.workflow.flow[insertStepIndex].step_number) step.step_number++;
    });

    $scope.workflow.flow.splice((insertStepIndex+1), 0, task_data);

}
```

For some reason, the array with id **1334f68e7d209ae6** get's changed to `step_number: 4` but get's completely ignored in the `ng-repeat`

This is what is displayed:

```
1
2
3
3
```

And when I console.log `$scope.workflow.flow` this is what I see:

```
[
  {
    "id":"1334f68db820f664",
    "step_number":1,
    "tasks":[ { "id":"1334f68e3f20f665" } ]
  },
  {
    "id":"134967a5ba205f5b",
    "step_number":2,
    "tasks":[ { "id":"134972c5b420e027" } ]
  },
  {
    "id":null,
    "step_number":3,
    "tasks":[]
  },
  {
    "id":"1334f68e7d209ae6",
    "step_number":4,
    "tasks":[ { "id":"1334f68ef6209ae7" } ]
  }
]
```

Does anyone know why this would happen?

---

### Below is a code snippet:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.workflow = {
      flow: [
      {
        "id":"1334f68db820f664",
        "step_number":1,
        "tasks":[ { "id":"1334f68e3f20f665" } ]
      },
      {
        "id":"134967a5ba205f5b",
        "step_number":2,
        "tasks":[ { "id":"134972c5b420e027" } ]
      },
      {
        "id":"1334f68e7d209ae6",
        "step_number":3,
        "tasks":[ { "id":"1334f68ef6209ae7" } ]
      }
    ]
    };

    $scope.insertStep = function() {

      var insertStepIndex = 1, 
          task_data = {"id": null, "step_number": (insertStepIndex+2), "tasks": []};

      //go through each item in the array
      $.each($scope.workflow.flow, function(index, step){
          //if the step number is greater then the place you want to insert it into, increase the step numbers
          if(step.step_number > $scope.workflow.flow[insertStepIndex].step_number) step.step_number++;
      });

      $scope.workflow.flow.splice((insertStepIndex+1), 0, task_data);
      
      console.log($scope.workflow.flow);
  }


  });
```

```html
  

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>      
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

      <div ng-click="insertStep()">Insert Step</div><br /><br />

      <div ng-repeat="data in workflow.flow | orderBy:'+step_number'" ng-init="$stepIndex = workflow.flow.indexOf(data)">
        {{ workflow.flow[$stepIndex].step_number }}
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: could you create a snippet here

Comment: @iceman I've added it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because `ng-init` was only running once, not again when the array was updated. I have to use this instead:

```
$scope.getIndex = function(data) {
  return $scope.workflow.flow.indexOf(data);
};
```

Like so:

```
{{ workflow.flow[getIndex(data)].step_number }}
```

Comment: I tried to make your life simpler, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do like this:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <div ng-click="insertStep()">Insert Step</div><br /><br />

  <div ng-repeat="data in workflow.flow | orderBy:'+step_number'">
    {{ data.step_number }}
  </div>
</div>
```

You don't have to calculate index by yourself. I changed your snippet a bit. No more `ng-init`, and using `data.step_number` instead of `workflow.flow[getIndex(data)].step_number`.

You also don't have to use splice, you could just use `push` since you're already ordering by step_number in `ng-repeat` (unless you really need the object in right place whithin the array).

### SNIPPET

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.workflow = {
      flow: [
      {
        "id":"1334f68db820f664",
        "step_number":1,
        "tasks":[ { "id":"1334f68e3f20f665" } ]
      },
      {
        "id":"134967a5ba205f5b",
        "step_number":2,
        "tasks":[ { "id":"134972c5b420e027" } ]
      },
      {
        "id":"1334f68e7d209ae6",
        "step_number":3,
        "tasks":[ { "id":"1334f68ef6209ae7" } ]
      }
    ]
    };

    $scope.insertStep = function() {

      var insertStepIndex = 1, 
          task_data = {"id": null, "step_number": (insertStepIndex+2), "tasks": []};

      //go through each item in the array
      $.each($scope.workflow.flow, function(index, step){
          //if the step number is greater than the place you want to insert it into, increase the step numbers
          if(step.step_number > $scope.workflow.flow[insertStepIndex].step_number) step.step_number++;
      });

      // you don't have to use splice at all, since you're ordering by step_number in ng-repeat, you could just push it (unless you really need the objects in the right place inside the array):

      $scope.workflow.flow.push(task_data);

      // $scope.workflow.flow.splice((insertStepIndex+1), 0, task_data);
      
  }


  });
```

```html
  

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>      
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

      <div ng-click="insertStep()">Insert Step</div><br /><br />

      <div ng-repeat="data in workflow.flow | orderBy:'+step_number'">
        {{ data.step_number }}
      </div>
    </div>
```